# Symfony 4: Exceptions not caught by kernel.exception listener with debugging disabled

Tags: exception, symfony4

When some specific exceptions are thrown in my application I would like to do something special (logging, redirects, ....)

I have registered an eventlistener:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

in dev-environment everything works just fine.

When in prod-environment (debug=false), onKernelException (in App\EventListener\ExceptionListener) is never called.

debugging the event-dispatcher confirms that my listener is not loaded.

```
php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.exception --env=dev
------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
Order   Callable                                                                            Priority  
------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
#1      App\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException()                            0         
#2      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException()    0         
#3      Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onException()   0         
#4      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException()   -128      
#5      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException()   -256      

php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.exception --env=prod
------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
Order   Callable                                                                            Priority  
------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
#1      Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onException()   0         
#2      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException()   -128
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong or why Symfony behaves this way?

Comment: try to clear the cache in the prod environment using php bin/console cache:clear -- --env=prod

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick